# How to avoid ORA-01427 in update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I know below subquery should return 1 row.
Can you let me know how to change below UPDATE query to update test1 table with mapping table's rows?

```
update test1 a set daily_value = ( select daily_value from mapping b where a.table_name = b.table_name);
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


create table test1
( table_name varchar2(10),
  daily_value varchar2(10)
)
/

insert into test1(table_name) values ('first');
insert into test1(table_name) values ('first');
commit;


create table mapping
( table_name varchar2(10),
  daily_value varchar2(10)
)
/

insert into mapping values ('first','value_1');
insert into mapping values ('first','value_2');
commit;



TEST1 table should have below data

TABLE_NAME  DAILY_VALUE
FIRST       value_1
FIRST       value_2
```

Comment: subquery return 2 rows of `value_1` and `value_2`

Comment: You have two equal rows in `test1`; how do you decide which one gets `value_1` and which `value_2`?

Comment: I don't need to distinguish value_1 & value_2 in test1 table. I just need to update test1 with 2 values.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and descripe how the values of table test1 should look after the update?

Comment: There is no Ansi-SQL way to do it since your tables don't provide keys to be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide on ordering criteria on your tables to decide which rows gets `value_1` and which one gets `value_2`.
Assuming you have no ordering, a simple `rownum` could work; for example:

```
merge into test1 t1
using( select daily_value, table_name, rownum as rn 
       from mapping
     ) M
on (M.table_name = t1.table_name and rownum = M.rn)     
when matched then 
    update set daily_value = M.daily_value
```

gives:

```
TABLE_NAME DAILY_VALUE
---------- -----------
first      value_1    
first      value_2
```

Comment: Great! Can you apply this logic into UPDATE statement? Little bit confused in doing that.

Comment: @Sigularity why can't you use the MERGE statement that Aleksej provided?

Comment: Sorry but I should apply this logic into other dbms as well like PostgreSQL.

Comment: I know nothing about Postgres, so I'd suggest you to edit the question to clarify that you need a solution both working in Oracle and Postgres and wait for someone who knows both systems

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. It works fine on Oracle at least.

Answer (score 0):

The update cannot return 1 row as it cannot distinguish both rows in table `test1` as they have the same value 'first'. If you change the data to have different values, it works as expected:

```
DELETE FROM mapping;
DELETE FROM test1;

INSERT INTO test1(table_name) VALUES ('first');
INSERT INTO test1(table_name) VALUES ('second');

INSERT INTO mapping VALUES ('first','value_1');
INSERT INTO mapping VALUES ('second','value_2');

update test1 a set daily_value = ( select daily_value from mapping b where a.table_name = b.table_name);
2 rows updated.
```

Personally, I prefer the `MERGE` statement, though, as I find it a bit clearer:

```
MERGE INTO test1 USING mapping 
   ON (test1.table_name = mapping.table_name)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
      test1.daily_value = mapping.daily_value;
```

Comment: Thanks for you comments. But, data set is very special case. I have to keep the same values in test1 with 'first'.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to select `MIN` or `MAX` of `(daily_value)`

```
UPDATE test1 a
SET
    daily_value = (
        SELECT
            MIN(daily_value)
        FROM
            mapping b
        WHERE
            a.table_name = b.table_name
    );
```

But, this will make your data in test1 like this

```
TABLE_NAME  DAILY_VALUE
first   value_1
first   value_1
```

If you don't want this, you should add another unique column which relates between the two tables other than `table_name`

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3d6b/1)